# Parse SASS list to find if item is 'true' and render one instance of CSS

Tags: sass

I need to parse a list that contains multiple 3-item lists like this:

```
$myList (item1, "something", true),
        (item2, "something", false),
        (item3, "something", true);
```

and find out if any of the third item of any of those lists equals `true`. In the example, in the first and third list, the third item is `true`. Further, I need to detect that and render, and just for one instance of this, render some CSS based off of it.

`@each` control directive can parse this, but the problem using this is that it will render CSS for each case of the list items being true.

```
@each $item in $myList {
    @if nth($item, 3) {
        [class*="item"] {
            float: left;
        }
    }
}
```

If the first and second items are set to `true`, the above will render:

```
[class*="item"] {
    float: left;
}
[class*="item"] {
    float: left;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What relevance does your list have to the selector you're generating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the CSS outside the loop and use a flag variable to track if it should be included or not. For example:

```
$use-float: false;

@each $item in $myList {
    @if nth($item, 3) {
        $use-float: true;
    }
}

@if $use-float {
    [class*="item"] {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, and now that I've seen what you did I'm wondering why I didn't think about it. lol

Appreciate the help.